# Shimano BR-RS805 hydraulic disc caliper alternatives?

Tags: shimano, hydraulic-disc-brake, caliper

I have a bike from early 2016 with Shimano BR-RS805 hydraulic disc calipers.

These need to be replaced, but are discontinued, and newer road/cross/gravel offerings from Shimano use BH90 hoses, while BR-RS805 uses BH59.

The levers are ST-RS785 Di2.

I don't mind another brand as long as they fit (flat-mount 140 mm rear (but I could use a wedge, and change to 160 mm), 160 mm front).

Comment: You can use any Shimano flat mount calipers or post mount with adapters, these are all cross-compatible. Lots of options to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

It is regularly stated that almost all Shimano hydraulic calipers are interchangeable excluding perhaps the DH ones, Saint, Zee etc. Therefore, you can choose one suitable for your frame and be sure it will work with your current lever.

It is important that you use the correct olive and barb for the hose you are using as there are some small differences to the inner and outer dimensions of the different shimano hoses.

There are also aftermarket calipers available by eg. Hope that have their own benefits and drawbacks.

Comment: If you replacing the caliper with a new one that uses the compression nut style hose attachment, it is likely that you can re-use the existing fittings on the end of the old hose (the barb, olive, and compression nut).  I believe that most shimano road calipers use this hose attachment method.  However, many of the shimano mountain calipers and some of the road calipers have a banjo bolt fitting, which would require a new hose.